# Substract 8 days + seconds from date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

Currently I have an update that sets a column like this:

```
UPDATE ... SET date_time = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 DAY)
...
```

So, `date_time` will hold the current date minus 8 days.  I have a variable in my PHP code that holds seconds. And I want to be able to subtract that from NOW() too. So, if this variable holds 299928 seconds ($seconds = 299928), I would like to be able to do:

`UPDATE ... SET date_time = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 DAY, $seconds)`. I fail to see how would I convert those seconds in a way that I can use in my MYSQL query, taking into account that I also want to subtract the 8 day interval.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to simply use another DATE_SUB function, wrapping your existing expression:

```
   = DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 DAY), INTERVAL 299928 SECOND)
```

Since your current expression is returning a `DATETIME`, it's valid to use that function as the argument of another function that expects a `DATETIME`. (Similar to the way the NOW() function is used as an argument in your existing `DATE_SUB` function.)